# mysql syntax error 1064 "NEW" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm getting an error message related to syntax. I've searched the MySql documentation and these forms and can't seem to find anything that works.

I'm trying to call a stored procedure within a trigger. If a patient has no family physician (hence Fam_Phys_SSN being null) then the procedure is called and they are assigned a family physician.

I'm using MySql workbench (MySql 8) and I get the error message:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL RETURN_PHYSICIAN(SSN);  END IF; END' at line 5

The error appears on the "NEW" in SET NEW.Fam_Phys_SSN...

My code is:

```
-- Write your stored procedure after this line
delimiter //
create procedure RETURN_PHYSICIAN(IN paSSN INT(11), OUT phSSN INT(11))
BEGIN

    select person.SSN INTO phSSN
    from person join physician using (SSN)
    where city = (select city from person where SSN = paSSN) 
       AND country = (select country from person where SSN = phSSN);

END//
DELIMITER ;
-- Write your trigger after this line and call the stored procedure in the body of the trigger.
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 BEFORE INSERT ON patient
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF Fam_Phys_SSN IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.Fam_Phys_SSN = CALL RETURN_PHYSICIAN(SSN);
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
-- Do not modify or delete the following lines. Do not write anything after this line.
insert into patient values('530166255', null, 'Noel.Jackson@a.com');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CALL` isn't an expression, it doesn't return a value. The result is an `OUT` parameter, so you need to put the column in the argument list.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 BEFORE INSERT ON patient
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Fam_Phys_SSN IS NULL THEN
        CALL RETURN_PHYSICIAN(NEW.SSN, NEW.Fam_Phys_SSN);
    END IF;
END//
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It worked. If I may ask another question, now my final insert statement is returning the error "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'SSN' in 'field list'
". From what I've gathered, it is related to the trigger. Within the new trigger, is there anything else I need to add in order to successfully complete the insert statement? Sorry for the follow-up question, I'm very new to SQL.

Comment: I don't see SSN in the final insert statement.

Comment: patient tables rows are of the form (SSN, Fam_Phys_SSN, email_address). I am not allowed to modify the final insert statement, unfortunately.

Comment: The error you got is coming from a query that contains the word `SSN`. The final insert statement doesn't contain that word, so the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: It's probably coming from the trigger, where does it get SSN from when calling `RETURN_PHYSICIAN()`?

Comment: It should be `NEW.SSN` in the call to the function.